# Django ManyToMany indirect lookup from list

Tags: python, django

Stupidly simple question i'm struggling with:

I have two models, parent and child

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child)
```

I have a list of Parent models from another query and want to get all children of those parents in a single query, something like:

```
children = Child.objects.filter(parent_set__contains=list_of_parents)
```

I know the above isn't right, but i'm struggling to put the ORM query together. Not even sure if this is doable without ORing some Q()s together?

I'm just getting starting to dig deeper in to the ORM past basic stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup and `parent` (lowercase name of the model) in filter:

```
children = Child.objects.filter(parent__in=list_of_parents)
```

Comment: Ah I see, I thought that Child would have required some formal definition of the "parent" attribute in the model. Nifty. The django docs could use more examples I recon :)